# HTTP 500 Response with Body?

Tags: http, spring-mvc, resteasy

I have a RESTEasy service that returns a HTTP 500 when a server side error occurs. I manage to attach a body to the HTTP response in order to give more details about the error. So the response that comes out of the service looks something like this

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Length: 3251
Date: Thu, 14 Oct 2010 23:22:49 GMT
Connection: close

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><myErrorEnvelope><internalCode>123</internalCode><description>error details</description></myErrorEnvelope>
```

I have a client (spring MVC 3.0 REST client) and I am trying to capture the HTTP 500 and read the body of the response and deserialize the *myErrorEnvelope* object. I first catch a catch *RestClientException* and it correctly tells me there was a HTTP 500 response but then there seems to be no way to get the Body of the response. Is this something I'm not supposed to be able to do? Am I supposed to return the error object as the body of a HTTP 200 response instead? I really would rather return HTTP 500 with a body.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

You're trying to do the right thing. A framework that doesn't let you get the payload of a non-2xx response simply is broken.

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: Public facing APIs prolly shouldn't provide any more details.  But if you have an internally facing API  you could save a bunch a troubleshooting time by including the error in the body.  400 is another candidate for providing additional information in the body.